# How to properly use the ChiSquareTest function in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, p-value, chi-squared

I'm just doing something basic from https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/chi-square-test.html

Which pet do you prefer?

P value is 0.043

I get an array of pValues: [0.157299207050285,0.157299207050285]
I don't understand that

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.stat import ChiSquareTest

data = [(0.0, Vectors.dense(207, 282)),
        (1.0, Vectors.dense(231, 242))]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["label", "features"])

r = ChiSquareTest.test(df, "features", "label").head()
print("pValues: " + str(r.pValues))
print("degreesOfFreedom: " + str(r.degreesOfFreedom))
print("statistics: " + str(r.statistics))
```

0.0 is male and 1.0 is female

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PySpark's ChiSquareTest is expecting the input data in a slightly different format.

If we assume the following feature encoding :

- Cat = 0.0
- Dog = 1.0
- Men = 2.0
- Women = 4.0

And the frequency of each feature as :

- freq(Cat, Men) = 207
- freq(Cat, Women) = 231
- freq(Dog, Men) = 282
- freq(Dog, Women) = 242

You need to rewrite the input dataframe as :

```
data = [(0.0, Vectors.dense(2.0)) for x in range(207)] + [(0.0, Vectors.dense(4.0)) for x in range(231)]\
        + [(1.0, Vectors.dense(2.0)) for x in range(282)] + [(1.0, Vectors.dense(4.0)) for x in range(242)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["label", "features"])

df.show()

# +-----+--------+
# |label|features|
# +-----+--------+
# |  0.0|   [2.0]|
# |  0.0|   [2.0]|
# |  0.0|   [2.0]|
# |  0.0|   [2.0]|
# |  0.0|   [2.0]|
# |  0.0|   [2.0]|
# |  0.0|   [2.0]|
# |  0.0|   [2.0]|
# |  0.0|   [2.0]|
# |  0.0|   [2.0]|
# |  0.0|   [2.0]|
# |  0.0|   [2.0]|
# |  0.0|   [2.0]|
# |  0.0|   [2.0]|
# |  0.0|   [2.0]|
# |  0.0|   [2.0]|
# |  0.0|   [2.0]|
# |  0.0|   [2.0]|
# |  0.0|   [2.0]|
# |  0.0|   [2.0]|
# +-----+--------+
```

If you then run `ChiSquareTest`, you will see the expected result.

```
r = ChiSquareTest.test(df, "features", "label")

r.show(truncate=False)

# +---------------------+----------------+-------------------+
# |pValues              |degreesOfFreedom|statistics         |
# +---------------------+----------------+-------------------+
# |[0.04279386669738339]|[1]             |[4.103526475356584]|
# +---------------------+----------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Ok so the ChiSquareTest also does the counting of the elements as well. Thank you

Comment: What if I wanted to scale this and do the counting else where? millons of rows?

Comment: In terms of scalability, Spark can handle more than millions of rows. I regularly work with billions of rows of Spark computation on a single machine. If the counting is done elsewhere, it is better if you use an alternative implementation like `scipy.stats.chi2_contingency`. It is very unlikely that you will have a contingency table so big that scipy cannot handle.